# AsyncTask error ANDROID

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement an asynctask for a method but i met with an error. I dont know what is the problem or where did i done wrong.

**Below is my code**

```
class abc extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            } else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is the part where i got error**

```
parameters.putString("message", message);
```

**ERROR saying:** The method putString(String, String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[])

Comment: Do not perform ui operations in doInBackground. Do it in onPostExecte() and onPreexecute().

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with this

String... is a datatype, which accept a set of strings. So you can't typecast it to String.

I understand your problem and the simplest fix for this is

Change

```
parameters.putString("message", message);
```

to

```
parameters.putString("message", message[0]);
```

So this will take the first string passed to the asynctask.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: error saying that the array index out of bound exception error

Comment: You have to pass the message string as a parameter to `execute()`.

Comment: Then why do you have a message parameter. Why don't you make it Void

Answer (score 2):

The error states out that you are trying to call a method with wrong parameter types. The method expects a `String` as the second parameter but you are using `String[]` (String array).

The solution for this error is fairly easy in this case as the Android API provides a method for `String[]`. Just replace

```
parameters.putString("message", message);
```

with

```
parameters.putStringArray("message", message);
```

---

As you only want the first element use this code. It checks the length of the array to avoid the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

```
if (message.length > 0) {
    parameters.putString("message", message[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible if i can change the String[] to string instead?

Comment: @Justin: As `message` is an array you can simply choose the first element with `parameters.putString("message", message[0]);`. But you need to check the length because `message` could be empty.

Comment: i change that to message[0] but error saying index out of bound exception

Comment: @Justin: Updated my answer. But if you get this, you should check your program logic as you are expecting `message` to have at least one element.